# How am I going to store the value from the dropdown to the barcode widget?

Tags: php, yii2

I need to transfer the selected product code from the dropdown to the bar code generator att.

```
<?php $dataStorageLocation = ArrayHelper::map(StorageLocation::find()>all(),'storage_id','storage_id'); ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">    

  <?= $form->field($model, 'product_code', ['template' => '<div class="col-sm-3         text-right">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">{input}</div>{hint}        {error}'])->dropDownList($dataStorageLocation);

$optionsArray = array(
'elementId'=> 'showBarcode', /* div or canvas id*/
'value'=> '$model', /* value for EAN 13 be careful to set right values for each barcode type */
'type'=>'code128',/*supported types  ean8, ean13, upc, std25, int25, code11, code39, code93, code128, codabar, msi, datamatrix*/

);
echo BarcodeGenerator::widget($optionsArray); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i Only add $model->product_code inside the value.